# Wordpress Drop down menu Width reduce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have developed wordpress [**website**](http://www.watchedge.com) using Woo commerce plugin and I have  created  drop menu.

In my Site I have watch brands, knife brands and also some unwanted images deleted from watch brands. Now drop down of watch menu having extra `width`, its showing **empty black area** in Watches drop-down menu. I can't figure it out that how To reduce it ?

please help me into this.

Comment: Always study carefully the documentation of each plugin you use.
Meanwhile your 'watches' menu `<li>` has class `menu-full-width` viz causing its dropdown to occupy full container width, remove it and it will do the trick for you.

Comment: I will remove from css @vivekkupadhyay ?

Comment: from your `HTML` structure, not for the `CSS`!

Comment: ok  thank you @vivekkupadhyay bro i will check let u inform

Comment: bro  if i remove that line   multi column menu change single drop down its issues